# ¿Cómo cargar una imagen almacenada en un byte[] dentro de un img de JSP?

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, spring-mvc

¿Cómo puedo poner una imagen en `byte[]` en una etiqueta `<img>` en mi JSP?
La idea es mostrar una imagen cargada desde la base de datos en byte y mostrar en un jsp.

Comment: Las preguntas en este sitio deben ser en español debes traducir tu respuesta, tu pregunta no es relacionado con el sitio Saludos.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés y debería ser traducida para que se acepte en Stack Overflow en español.

Comment: hola, ¿cómo lo puedo poner una imagen en byte [] en una etiqueta  IMG de JSP.
La idea es mostrar una imagen cargada desde la base de datos en byte y mostrar en un jsp. muchas gracias!

Comment: gracias Luiggi por editar la pregunta! que pena soy nuevo!

Comment: @MarioGarcia Convirtiendo esos bytes a base 64 y poniendo eso en el atributo src.

Comment: Gracias @ArtEze esa era La respuesta! base64!

Comment: Duplicado exacto de: **[¿cómo poner una imagen en byte \[\] en una etiqueta IMG de JSP?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/25145/127)**