# ¿cómo poner una imagen en byte [] en una etiqueta IMG de JSP?

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring

Buenas Noches quisiera saber cómo puedo poner una imagen parseada en byte [] en una etiqueta IMG de JSP. La idea es mostrar una imagen cargada desde la base de datos (blob) en byte y mostrar en un jsp. muchas gracias!

Answer (score 5):

Para esto puedes convertir ese `byte[]` a `base64` y enviarla al cliente.

**Java 8**

```
byte[] photo = user.getPhoto();
String bphoto = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(photo);
// enviarla al cliente
```

En el cliente la muestras:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,${bphoto}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria así:

```
  <img id='base64image' src='data:image/png;base64,<!-- datos en base64 -->' />
```

Answer (score -1):

Para el cliente de la siguiente manera funciona bien:

```
<img id='base64image' src='data:image/png;base64,img.getBytes' />
```

Comment: Bienvenido Edwin la seccion de respuestas no es para agradecer o dejar comentarios. Por favor realiza el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Por otra parte chequea [Como escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hola Edwin, deberías añadir algo más de detalle. ¿Qué es `img.getBytes`? ¿qué es lo que hace o cómo funciona? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.